# jquery infinitescroll error on IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I just playing with masonry and infinitescroll and only IE(8) give me back an error.

the page is here: 
http://unknoweb.com/clienti/danive/en/collection/FallWinter_1011/

on IE masonry and infinitescroll don't start and ruin all the other code.
The error is:

```
Messaggio: Property o method not supported by the object
Linea: 15
Carattere: 25
Codice: 0
URI: http://unknoweb.com/clienti/danive/js/jquery.infinitescroll.js
```

line 15 on infinitescroll is:

```
if (opts.debug) { window.console && console.log.call(console,arguments)}
```

someone can help me?

regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

if this can help, try adding `debug: false` in the option...

Comment: thanks.
now the header slider run but infinitescroll don't want to load other page.